# about alarm manager in android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-preferences, android-alarms

I have made an alarm manager to schedule some user defined events and it is working successfully
then I have made a setting screen (from preference activity) to let the user to change some setting like (days before alarm)

my question is If I schedule the event before event start date by 3 days, then the user change the days before from setting to one day only

then I schedule the event again before event start date by 1 day, is that mean the user will be notified twice

- one before 3 days
- one before 1 day

if that is true so how can I prevent that from happening

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each alarm is accompanied by a PendingIntent which has a unique hash identifier. When using the same identifier, that alarm will overwrite the former as stated in the documentation:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

> Schedule an alarm. Note: ...If there is already an alarm scheduled for the same IntentSender, it will first be canceled...

Note that PendingIntent are characterized by their parameters and identifiers.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, YourTarget.class);
// The hashcode works as an identifier here. By using the same, the alarm will be overwrriten
PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mContext, hashCode, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
    mAlarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
} else {
    mAlarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public void cancel (PendingIntent operation)
>
> Remove any alarms with a matching Intent. Any alarm, of any type, whose Intent
> ```
>
> matches  this one (as defined by filterEquals(Intent)),
>   will be canceled.

So you can  call [cancel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#cancel%28android.app.PendingIntent%29) on your pending intent alarmManager.cancel(myPendingIntent)
and the create a new one with a new time.

But you dont have to call cancel explicitly because as long as filterEquals returns true when comparing your new PendingIntent with the previous one then your alarm will start only 1 day before.

> public boolean filterEquals (Intent other)
>
> ```
> Determine if two intents are the same for the purposes of intent resolution
> ```
>
> (filtering).  That is, if their action, data, type, class,
>   and categories are the same. This does not compare any extra data
>   included in the intents.